# Using dplyr to remove duplicates conditionally

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset in longformat that contains both visit and measure dates for each ID. What I want is to remove the duplicate visit dates for each ID conditionally, namely:

IF visit date - measure date does not equal 0, then I want the to include the first visit date.

IF visit date - measure date is a draw, however, then I want to include the lastest visit date.

I already wrote part of the code using `dplyr`. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to code the second part of the condition.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1), 
                 VISIT = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-01")),
                 MEASURE = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-01")),
                 VALUE = c(5, 10))

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(DIFF = abs(VISIT - MEASURE)) %>%
  arrange(DIFF) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  group_by(VISIT) %>%
  # If DIFF dates is != 0, I want the first value
  # If DIFF dates is a draw, I want the latest value
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you try to achieve, but maybe this could help you. I adjusted the example dataframe a bit, maybe you will need to edit yours in your question such that it makes sense. In your example data DIFF dates is never unequal to 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  VISIT = c(
    as.Date("2020-01-01"),
    as.Date("2020-01-01"),
    as.Date("2020-01-01"),
    as.Date("2020-01-02")
  ),
  MEASURE = c(
    as.Date("2020-01-01"),
    as.Date("2020-01-01"),
    as.Date("2020-01-01"),
    as.Date("2020-01-03")
  ),
  VALUE = c(5, 10, 15, 20)
)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    DIFF = abs(VISIT - MEASURE),
    # get days as a digit
    DIFF = stringr::str_extract(DIFF, "\\d+") %>% as.numeric(),
    # your if conditions
    DIFF_filter = case_when(
      DIFF != 0 ~ min(VISIT),
      DIFF == 0 ~ max(VISIT)
    )
  )
```